# DrawerNavigationListAdapter with icons

Tags: java, android

I just started developing for android, and I'm having a problem. I a DrawerNavigationListAdapter and a DrawerNavigationListView, and is working perfectly, now I'm trying to add to this a respective icons.

Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="@drawable/navigation_list_selector" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the DrawerNavigationListView.java

```
public class DrawerNavigationListView extends ListView implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    public DrawerNavigationListView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public DrawerNavigationListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DrawerNavigationListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        DrawerNavigationListAdapter adapter = new DrawerNavigationListAdapter( getContext(), 1 );
        adapter.add(getContext().getString(R.string.section_0));
        ...
        setAdapter( adapter );

        setOnItemClickListener( this );
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        EventBus.getInstance().post(new DrawerSectionItemClickedEvent((String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)));
    }
}
```

and the DrawerNavigationListAdapter

```
public class DrawerNavigationListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public DrawerNavigationListAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if( convertView == null ) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate( R.layout.navigation_drawer_list_item, parent, false );
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.title );
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            convertView.setTag( holder );
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(getItem(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        ImageView icon;
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I change this code so I can add the icons?

Comment: How are the icons not being added correctly?

Comment: because I'm not adding them. I'm looking for something like adapter.add(getContext().getString(R.string.section_0));

Comment: Do your text views display in the navigation drawer, just not the image views?

Comment: yes the text appear correctly, but not the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RelativeLayouts, views listed after others will be drawn at a higher z-index unless otherwise instructed. So your TextView is effectively drawing over your ImageView. You need to either use

```
android:layout_toRightOf="ImageView" //or layout_toLeftOf
```

in the xml of your TextView or use

```
android:drawableLeft="ImageView" //or drawableRight
```

The latter is how I add icons to TextViews in adapters, but either works.

Comment: thanks for this, will be necessary, but this doesnt answer my question, the icons are not there because I didnt added them, I want to know how to add the icons

Comment: In your ImageView xml, you're missing the android:src="@drawable/..." element. Look here: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imageview-example/